# How to Search multiple colors in a window?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I want to search multiple colors in the same region on a specific window.

Is there a way to use the pixel search feature to search more then one color at a time or do I need to cycle the pixel search command over and over again like this :

```
F12:: {
if PixelSearch(&Px, &Py, 41, 23, 686, 171, 0xFFFFFF, 1) and PixelSearch(&Px, &Py, 41, 23, 686, 171, 0x000000, 1) {
    MsgBox("found")
}
```

So, I want something like this :

```
F12:: {
    Colors := 0xFFFFFF And [or] 0x000000
    if PixelSearch(&Px, &Py, 41, 23, 686, 171,Colors , 1) {
        MsgBox("found")
    }
```

Any help to do that Please!

Answer (score 1):

```
F12:: {
Color1 := 0xFFFFFF
Color2 := 0x000000
Colors := Color1 | Color2

if PixelSearch(&Px, &Py, 41, 23, 686, 171, Colors, 1) {
    MsgBox("found")
}}
```

That should work!